# Limit findAll possible with Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-data

Is it possible with Springs auto implemented repositories to limit the result size of the findAll method?

I'm trying to have something like the following declared in the interface:

```
List<XY> findAllTopTen();
```

Unfortunatelly, it doesn't work (this) way...

Comment: *"it doesn't work (this) way"* - what way *does* it work in, then? Edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pass a `Pageable` as a parameter like following:

```
Page<x> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 33):

If you dont have a `Pageable` object that came from your controller and just need to get X amount of objects from DB, you can do the following:

First, your Repository class has to extend `JpaRepository<T, ID>` so it wil be able to query using a Pageable object.

Second, you can define a Pageable object this way:

```
Pageable limit = PageRequest.of(0,10);
return repository.findall(limit);
```

In this case, the query would return the first 10 objects.

You can find more info [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) (Scroll down to 4.1, Example 4)
Note that the example actually extends `PagingAndSortingRepository` but `JpaRepository` contains all the methods from `PagingAndSortingRepository` and has additional functions aswell.

Edit: Thanks to @Zunnii for pointing out that `new PageRequest()` is now deprecated. I edited the snippet above to reflect that.

Comment: As of now, PageRequest is already deprecated, so you can use `PageRequest.of(0, 10)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly specify the ordering, otherwise Spring Data JPA has no way of deciding what criteria it should use. For instance:

```
List<XY> findAllTopTenByAge();
```

See more details in the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result).

Comment: how do you use that in RepositoryRestResource