# how to fetch only 80 rows from mysql database using Spring Data @query annotation?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My query like this

```
@Query("select cnt from Content cnt  order by 
CASE WHEN cnt.status = 'rejected' THEN '1' 
WHEN cnt.status = 'modified'  ELSE cnt.status END ASC")
```

how to add limit **0,100** rows to add my `query`?

I wrote below format ,but all rows fetched from `database`

```
@Query("select cnt from Content cnt  
  order by CASE WHEN cnt.status = 'rejected' THEN '1' 
  WHEN cnt.status = 'modified'  ELSE cnt.status END ASC limit 0,100")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote an answer to a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33024941/1995130). In your case the query would be the first you wrote but you would have to pass an Pageable object as a parameter. Assuming you read the linked answer, and know that your Repository should extend `JpaRepository` or `PagingAndSortingRepository`, it would look like this:

```
@Query("select cnt from Content cnt 
       order by CASE WHEN cnt.status = 'rejected' THEN '1' 
       WHEN cnt.status = 'modified'  ELSE cnt.status END ASC")
public List<Content> getContents(Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pagination (this is available in JPA and also in Hibernate as your JPA provider)

**Hibernate**:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("..YOUR QUERY HERE...");
query.setFirstResult(0);
query.setMaxResults(100);
List<Content> contentList = query.list();
```

JPA [Query](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html) also supports `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults` methods.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
@Query("....")
List<Object> countLimited(..., Pageable pageable);
```